# Better ways to write this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below table structure

> Users (PK - UserId)
>   System (PK - SystemId)
>   SystemRoles (PK-SystemRoleId, FK - SystemId)
>   UserRoles (PK-UserId & SystemRoleId, FK-SystemRoleId, FK-UserId)

`Users` can have access to different `Systems` and one `System` can have different `SystemRoles` defined.

Now, I need to delete `Users` who have `SystemRoles` assigned to them ONLY for a specific `System`(s). If they have `SystemRoles` defined for other `Systems`, they should not be deleted.

I have come up the below query to identify the records that are eligible for delete but think this can surely be optimized. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT U.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        distinct UR.UserID
    FROM
        dbo.UserRole UR
        INNER JOIN dbo.SystemRole SR ON (SR.SystemRoleID = UR.SystemRoleID)
        INNER JOIN dbo.[System] S ON (S.SystemID = SR.SystemID)
    WHERE 
        S.SystemName = 'ABC' OR S.SystemName = 'XYZ'
) T
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] U ON (U.UserID = T.UserID)
WHERE T.UserID NOT IN
(
    select 
        distinct UR.UserID 
    from 
        dbo.[UserRole] UR
        INNER JOIN dbo.SystemRole SR ON (SR.SystemRoleID = UR.SystemRoleID)
        INNER JOIN dbo.[System] S ON (S.SystemID = SR.SystemID)
    WHERE 
        S.SystemName <> 'ABC' 
    AND S.SystemName <> 'XYZ'
)
```

Comment: what's wrong with it? is it slow? are you sure it's slow? If it ain't broke...

Comment: if there isn't anything wrong with it, perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to go.

Comment: You have not forgotten adding indices, right? Especially for unique IDs

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it but I think this could be optimized or made even simpler. There is no problem with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of structure will get you the records you need.

```
select yourfields  -- or delete
from userroles 
where userid in 
(select userid 
from userroles join etc
where system.name = the one you want
except
select userid 
from userroles join etc
where system.name <> the one you want
)
```

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
select userid from (
        SELECT
            UR.UserID,
            max(case when (S.SystemName = 'ABC' OR S.SystemName = 'XYZ')
                then 1 else 0 end) as kill,
            max(case when (S.SystemName <> 'ABC' AND S.SystemName <> 'XYZ') 
                then 1 else 0 end) as keep
        FROM
            dbo.UserRole UR
            INNER JOIN dbo.SystemRole SR ON (SR.SystemRoleID = UR.SystemRoleID)
            INNER JOIN dbo.[System] S ON (S.SystemID = SR.SystemID)
        group by UR.UserID
) u where kill = 1 and keep = 0
```

Comment: right in line with what I would have run with... nice and clean.  One pass through, checking for both. I would have just altered slightly to max( case when condition / 1 / 0 ) and max( case when NOT condition / 1 / 0 ) which is the anything else.

Comment: +1 for the approach. There is no difference in terms of performance compared to doing 2 pass check. Both are returning about 200,000 records within a sec. The execution plan shows a Index Scan on System table whereas for the other query it is Index Seek. This certainly is not a problem in my case as there are only less than 50 rows in System table, I wonder how this query would perform if the System table has thousands of rows.